# Example applications that use the OpenThread stack to communicate

Tags: openthread

I have been playing around with OpenThead for about a month and I have set up two TI CC2538s in an OpenThread network, currently, I can send pings between them and modify the network parameters using the CLI, but they aren't capable of much else.

I would like to develop an application for them that is capable of transmitting some form of data using the OpenThread stack, maybe something simple at first like transmitting a block of text, however, I am not really sure where to start with this, are there any example applications that I could use as a starting point?

Comment: You could use java sockets  and read about TCP Connection

Comment: @BasilBattikhi, just wanting to clarify that we are talking about the same thing, I don't believe that OpenThread supports TCP or java, I believe it is all UDP and c/c++, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: What OS are you using? If you use Windows to control the devices, you can write any Windows application you want; including sockets.

Comment: They are independent of any OS, you flash the CC2538s and then they run the OpenThread protocol by themselves. There isn't really any OS as such as far as I'm aware

Comment: That is incorrect. On Windows, the OS supports running the OpenThread logic on the host, not the device. See architecture overview here: https://github.com/openthread/openthread/blob/master/examples/drivers/windows/README.md

Comment: Cheers Nick, unfortunately this won't work in my implementation but it is good to know. Just out of interest does this require the NCP version instead of the SOC one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application layers that sit directly on top of OpenThread, Nordic has released some examples in their [nRF5 SDK for Thread](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF5-SDK-for-Thread).

Also note that Thread (and OpenThread) implement an IPv6 link capable of transporting vanilla IPv6 datagrams.  As a result, you could run other transport protocols like TCP.  However, UDP is often recommended due to relatively high loss rates and latency variance that is common to low-power, wireless mesh networks.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look into it when I get a bit of free time, are there no examples that are a bit more general, i.e. not specifically for Nordic devices?

Comment: The nRF5 SDK example code is fairly general and worthwhile to reference if you're interested in CoAP.  The OpenThread CLI also provides simple commands for interacting with OpenThread's CoAP implementation.

Comment: Thanks jhui I saw that a CoAP CLI example had recently been added when I looked a few days ago, I have had a look through it and it seems to clear things up a bit.